# Which hadoop components are installed by default?

Tags: bigdata, apache-zookeeper, hadoop2

I am trying to install Hadoop for development. I did not install Hadoop from Cloudera as I have limited RAM of 8gb and it is not advisable to install CDH VM. Hence I am installing hadoop manually by downloading the tar file and then unpacking it (hadoop-2.8.0.tar.gz. I want to try out the entire ecosystem in Hadoop as I am following Hadoop A definitive guide book.

MY QUESTIONS:

1. Which ecosystem components are installed by default in such an installation ?
2. Do I need to install ZooKeeper separately or it is already present?
3. Would the components clash due to such an installation and what are the precautions that I need to take in  order to avoid this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That archive includes just HDFS and MapReduce framework. It is enough to get you started with hadoop, but it doesn't include any other projects from hadoop ecosystem. You might get away with running Cloudera QuickStart VM on a 8GB virtual machine. If you want to give a try to other projects (e.g. Spark, Hive, HBase...), that's the way to go, as you'll have a hard time integrating all those projects from hadoop ecosystem together by yourself.

Regarding your other questions:

- No, zookeeper is not present in the archive that you have downloaded
  (and you don't need it if you just want to use HDFS and MapReduce on
  one VM).
- No, the components won't "clash" (keep in mind, there are just two
  components - HDFS and MapReduce - that you have in your hadoop-2.8
  archive).

Comment: I Mac mini is of 8gb and then I gave 4gb to the VM. It's performance was pathetic. I read about setting up pseudo distributed mode and got started with,but for rest of of the tech something needs to be done.

Comment: By 'clash' I mean when I install rest of  the components would there be a situation where some part of the tech are common and some of those override each others effect resulting into wrong answers. As in this case the mistake would be in the installation and not in my code but that would result in time wastage. @facha